# Delphi Rest Client: TDsRestConnection as TRestClient

Tags: rest, delphi, reflection, client, firedac

I want write a client application that consumes Rest webservice from a server,
but I want to use the reflections components from Firedac. 
The problem is ... those components connect to a TDsRestConnection component, and I haven´t a server Rest, only a webservice.
How can I do for "cast" a TdsRestConnection as TRestClient or how I can access with Firedac reflections to objects ? Is it possible?

Comment: What's stopping you writing your own FireDAC-based REST server?

Comment: Which server? Are you planning on coding your own server?

Comment: No, I'm not planning coding a rest server, only a webservice in server side, and a client application with (is my wish) FireDac reflection classes for handling json datasets

Comment: You can't. The DS in TDSRestConnection stands for DataSnap. Either you are using a Datasnap server that enables JSONReflect functionality or you are not. Make up your mind.